# Does Ireland collect API data for EU Passengers?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, ireland, passport-stamps, advance-passenger-information

The EU directive implemented by the Irish government in 2018 means that extra-EU flights need to provide Advance Passenger Information for all passengers on the flight.

However, it is unclear if passengers traveling from within Schengen, lets say France, will also have their API stored in Ireland. Does anyone know what happens in this case?